# Ecliptic rotation around parent object

Tags: unity, rotation

It seems to be answers.unity.com not working for a couple of days, so I ask my question here.

Well, I'm using Unity and I have two objects (A and B). Object A is a parent of object B and object B is rotating around object A executing RotateAround function.

[image]

And everything is fine until I rotate the  object A. In this situation I get a mess I can't explain because of lack of geometry knowledge.

**But I have to be able to rotate object A with object B keeps its round ecliptical orbit around object A.**

[image]

How can I do it in code?..

*Sorry for a messy question and bad English. Hope those pictures help to understand what I want. Thanks to you all.*

Comment: There are several ways to use the RotateAround function, so this question would be clearer if you showed the code you're currently using, and explained how the results of that code differ from what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found. [Already answered question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724961/how-to-make-a-gameobject-rotate-around-another-gameobject-in-unity-in-the-rotati)

In my case I had to change the code kinda this way:

```
objB.transform.RotateAround(objA.transform.position, objB.transform.up, 1);
```